# How to make jquery toggle width animation stop midway to close again?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Maybe the question is confusing but let me give you an example, when I spam click the button that toggles the width, the div with keep on animating way after the button press and it doesn't look amazing. What I want is for the div to stop midway and go the other way and not complete its existing animation when the button is pressed again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuToggle').click(function() {
    $(".menuContainer").animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menuContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuContainer">
  <!-- Menu Items -->
</div>
<h4 class="menuToggle">Show Menu</h4>
```

Here is the fiddle, so you can see what exactly what I'm talking about. Try spamming the "Show Menu" button.

https://jsfiddle.net/x14usdga/5/

Help would be greatly appreciated, I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find anything on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuToggle').click(function() {
    $(".menuContainer").stop().animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menuContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuContainer">
  <!-- Menu Items -->
</div>
<h4 class="menuToggle">Show Menu</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if element is not animated before do animation

https://api.jquery.com/is/
https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menuToggle').click(function(){
    if( $('.menuContainer').is(':animated') ) { return false; }
    $(".menuContainer").animate({width: 'toggle'});
  }); 
});
```

```css
.menuContainer{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 15vw;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuContainer">    
    <!-- Menu Items -->
    </div>
    <h4 class="menuToggle">Show Menu</h4>
```